# Time calculation (round time to next time slot)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

For doing some statistics on my incoming data on webserver I do some ETL work on this data. So I aggregate some thing based on quarter hours. I.e.:

```
inserted  | tstamp
8:00        8:00
8:09        8:00
8:16        8:15
8:29        8:15
8:42        8:30
8:45        8:45
8:59        8:45
9:01        9:00
```

The columns above are `datetime` column, which also contain a date (I left it out only for demonstration purposes). The job runs every 3 minutes via cron and takes only data from last 3 minutes. Now, when the cron jobs crash while working, there is the risk, that a time slot contains wrong data when the jobs restarts next time. So I want the job to begin at last slot. I.e. when the job runs at 08:24 last and crash it should start again at 08:15.

My question is now, is there a simple MySQL statement which gives me the last time slot before the actual time?

The statement I'm using in ETL to determine actual time slot is

```
CONCAT(
    DATE_FORMAT(a.inserted, '%Y-%m-%d %H:'),
    IF(MINUTE(a.inserted)<15,'00',
        IF(MINUTE(a.inserted)<30,'15',
        IF(MINUTE(a.inserted)<45,'30',
        '45'))
    ),
    ':00'
) AS tstamp
```

Could this be done in a more elegant way?

Comment: Your query implies that your `real_time` column is not a date. Is it?

Comment: Sorry, that was only an example for time slot. For sure, it's a `datetime` column containing also a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unix_timestamp()` to get the current time in number of seconds since 1970.  The last 3-minute interval is that time modulo 3*60 seconds:

```
select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - mod(unix_timestamp(), 180))
            as StartOfInterval
,       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - mod(unix_timestamp(), 180)-180) 
            as StartOfLastInterval
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/930/0)

Comment: I meant an interval of 15 minutes ;) but I prefer your solution nevertheless, because I'm doing some more time calculations in PHP. So I use time functions in PHP and include the calculated stamp in my SQL query

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.  How about this?

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT( a.inserted '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') +
     INTERVAL (MINUTE(a.inserted) - MINUTE(a.inserted)%15) MINUTE
```

Comment: Really great approach (I wish I could give to accepts ;) but because I'm doing some more time calculations in PHP I use @Andomars hint

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`FLOOR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) to round minutes down to multiples of `15`:

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.inserted, '%Y-%m-%d %H:'), 
    15 * FLOOR(MINUTE(a.inserted) / 15)), ':00') AS tstamp
```

or use `FLOOR()` on the time and format that:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(900 * FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.inserted) / 900)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s') as tstamp
```

(`900` is the number of seconds in 15 minutes)